# Preloading expensive resources

Tags: .net

I have a significant quantity of external resources that I need to load.  It takes about 5 minutes to fully load (about 16 gigs of data).  These are basically third party image patterns that I have to deserialize.  I then use these in my application to process images.  They all get used and they get used often.

Ideally I would like to preload these once so that when the other application is closed and reopened, all the images do not have to be loaded again.  What is the best practice for creating a memory preloader that can share these resources with another process?

**Solutions**

The approaches I came up with are:

RAMDisk:  This makes the data much easier to access and manipulate.  Works well since I am only reading the files once at startup to deserialize them.  Changes do not effect the program at all.

Memory Mapped Files:  This approach is really best suited for operations that include writing, for streaming data that will fit in fixed size blocks, or fixed size data structures.

Comment: Shared memory seems the easiest way. You could create a shared memory pool big enough to hold the data and look for a fixed ID when the consumer proccesses start

Comment: By shared memory, are you referring to Memory Mapped Files?

Comment: 16 gigs is a lot.  You might load on demand to at least get started processing images.  Read ahead and load the next pattern on a separate thread.

Comment: Demand is unpredictable and we have to respond within 500ms.  Right now, they all get preloaded at the application start.  The loading process takes a good bit, though.  I am curious how MMF or IPC would effect access time.  Basically, I'm processing 1.5 images of parts on a conveyor and identifying them.  Loading as I go is possible to decrease latency, but preloading into memory would be ideal.  What I'm really trying to do is reduce downtime in the event of an application crash.  5 minutes is 450 parts lost to downtime.

Comment: How often are you crashing?  A second computer?

Comment: Once we've been running for a while, I expect it to never occur.  But during the early days of deployment I suspect we will see several unknown bugs pop up.  I'm really looking for a shared memory or IPC style solution as restarts will likely be accompanied by software changes and will not be as big of a concern after the system is stable.  I'm also open to reasons why I shouldn't from a best practices standpoint.